# Links not using FQDN on Sharepoint Mysite from an external access

Tags: sharepoint

I've configured external access to some sharepoint applications, including MySites, using AAM and ISA configuration.

Every seems working well, but when using the external access (ie via https), some links are not working because they use the internal name (http://mysite) instead of the FQDN via https (https://mysite.mydomain.fr*)

Any hint or suggestion are welcome.

*yes, i'm french.  =)

EDIT : examples of links that are not working :
- when clicking on a folder in a library
- when clicking on "My links" then "My sharepoint sites" and then clicking on one of the links displayed

Answer (score 1):

your alternate access mappings need to be consistent for each zone. If your sharepoint application that is exposed to the external users has an AAM for internet zone e.g. http(s)://www.portal.mycompany.com, you also have to add an AAM for your mysite sarepoint app for the internet zone as well e.g. http(s)://mysite.mycompany.com. if the internet zine is missing for mysite, the default zone will be used and that explains why you see the internal name in the link to mysite when pages are rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you need to set up alternate access mappings.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263208.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/tothesharepoint/archive/2008/08/26/3112518.aspx

Comment: Yes, and that's what i'm refering to with "using AAM" : i've already set up Alternate Access Mapping (AAM), and everything's fine except some links that seems hardwritten with the internal URL.

Answer (score 0):

Right, AAM is the feature to use. Don´t trust anyone who advises to change bindings for SharePoint WebApplications in IIS manually.
If you still experience, that Links in Alert-Mails show the non-FQDN URL, then it is because the URL is stored when the alert gets created. In that case you need to use a script to find and change those alerts for any user.